# How to get selected text outside of current java program window?

Tags: java

I am working on a Java program which should output the selected text in other applications of the OS (browser, text-editor, pdf-reader etc.).

For example, I select some text on Stack-overflow and run my Java program, it should output the selected text.

I found the `getSystemSelection` method in the `Toolkit` class in `java.awt` package, but output of my program is `null`.

My program is as following -

```
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyProg {

        public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
        {

            // Get default Toolkit
            Toolkit T = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

            Clipboard c = T.getSystemSelection();

            System.out.println(c.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));
        }
    }
```

Does anyone has any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the method you mention will work for accessing the selected text anywhere within your own application. But the ability to do this across applications would be limited by the host operating system and the other application. In some cases it might be possible, but certainly not across the board. So there is not going to be a standard way to do this in Java. Perhaps an obscure library exists out there that does it. Likely it would require writing a JNI wrapper in a language like C and then accessing that from within Java, and that wrapper would need to have unique implementations for every supported platform.

A simple workaround would be to require that the user copy the selected text to the clipboard, at which point it would then be a simple matter to read from the clipboard in your program using `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData()`.

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciate it.